# Automatically connect to the web on windows startup

Tags: windows, connection, rundll32.exe

How can I automatically have windows connect to the web using a RAS "connect to" shortcut upon windows startup, Using the default RAS connection?

I think I saw some software that does that, but I prefer something that can be done without downloading additional software. (I think that `rundll32.exe <something>` could do the trick).

See this [python snippet](https://seattle.cs.washington.edu/browser/seattle/trunk/dist/win/python/Lib/site-packages/win32/Demos/rastest.py?rev=73) for win32api example of handling RAS using win32api.

Comment: What Windows version? The thing I found is for NT...

Comment: Let's take XP and above. I don't think XP has a much different RAS interface in this regard then older NT based windowses.

Answer (score 2):

Try to drag'n drop the connection icon in *Network Connection* into the startup folder.

Comment: Nope. It would show the "connect to" dialog, but wouldn't start connecting.

Comment: You can configure the connection to suppress this dialog, as far as i remember.